# For loop inside a Promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, automated-tests

I'm trying to obtain the number of elements who have a class of `btn btn-ok`, and then loop over each of them.

```js
element.all(by.css('.btn.btn-ok')).count()
  .then(function(count) {
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      element.all(by.css(".btn.btn-ok")).get(i).click(); // <-- error!
      element(by.css(".icon-issue-in-active-dropdown")).click();
      element(by.css(".icon-check-round")).click();
    }
  });
```

However I get an error stating that said line could not be reached

Comment: I would suggest using `.each()` instead of a for loop [reference here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each).  Then you can do something like `element.all(by.css(".btn.btn-ok")).each(function(elem) {  elem.click() });`  Would also reduce your code by removing that loop, and make it more DRY since you won't have to call that element locator twice.  Cause you only use `.count()` for your loop anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead of `get`, the former gives you the jQuery/jqLite object instead of DOM element. And use `trigger` (in angular's jqLite it's called `triggerHandler`).

```
element.all(by.css('.btn.btn-ok')).count()
  .then(function(count) {
    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      element.all(by.css(".btn.btn-ok")).eq(i).triggerHandler("click")
      element(by.css(".icon-issue-in-active-dropdown")).triggerHandler("click");
      element(by.css(".icon-check-round")).triggerHandler("click");
   }
});
```

Read the commentary but to clarify `angular.element` calls jQuery if you have it included, otherwise it uses a toned-down version of it called `jqLite`. [Here is more detail about this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

Comment: he's not using jquery - he's using angular jqlite.

Comment: @DanielA.White Edited the answer

Comment: @DanielA.White By the way, if jQuery is included in your project, angular defers all those calls to jQuery. From angular docs `If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or jqLite.` 

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element